# Filtering out a specific alpha range in a texture using nodes

Tags: animation, materials, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm attempting to recreate [the water texture effects used in various Nintendo games such as Super Mario Galaxy 2](https://youtu.be/8rCRsOLiO7k?t=673) using shader nodes on a single material. I've got the scrolling layered textures down, but I have no idea how to get that effect where the areas of a texture that fall in a specific alpha range are filtered out of the material output, allowing the brightest and darkest - but not the middle - values to show. How could I do that using nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify any of the inputs with a ColorRamp. You can add a high factor (white) for the low and the high alpha values and add a low factor (black) for the middle values, and adjust with the slider. Of course you can plug it into any of the shader inputs, not only the alpha.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get a very similar looking effect to the one in the video by first combining the textures with a MixRGB node, then connecting it to a ColorRamp per your input. [Here's the final result.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/553349591576346654/962425927961313290/water_blend.gif)